# IOStorageFamily deleted in error

Tags: macos, osx-mavericks

I have accidentally deleted the file System/Library/Extensions/IOStorageFamily.kext by mistake. I know how stupid this was!

Now my iMac (model 2008, running Mavericks) gets stuck on the grey startup screen and hangs forever after the Apple logo turns into a no entry sign whilst the wheel continues to turn forever, see the following link for image showing this screen:

[No entry sign on startup screen](http://www.extensions.in.th/amitiae/...ges/disk-1.jpg)

I have run Disk Utility from the install CD and repaired the disk permissions with no success.

I have tried to run the rescue partition by using the Command + R key but this just displays my exsisting HD and does not show another option.

I have tried to boot into single user start with no success. The screen eventually hangs and says it can not find IOStorageFamily.kext.

I have tried to boot into safe mode with no success. It simply fails with the no entry sign as above.

I have reset the PRAM but this did not make any difference.

I have done a hardware test using the D key on startup but this returned no errors.

Please can someone advise if there is any way to fix this problem and if the is then what is the best way to do it? I know that it is not a harddrive failing or anything else and is simply because I accidently deleted the IOStorageFamily.kext file. Surely there is a way to repair this?

I appreciate any help or advice.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to fix the problem by using the following method:

http://support.apple.com/kb/PH13842

It says:

> If you have two Mac computers with FireWire or Thunderbolt ports, you
>   can connect them so that one of them appears as an external hard disk
>   on the other. This is called “target disk mode.”
>
> Connect the two computers with a FireWire or Thunderbolt cable. Start
>   up the computer to be used as a disk in target disk mode: If the
>   computer is off, start it up while holding down the T key.
>
> If the computer is on, choose Apple menu > System Preferences, click
>   Startup Disk, then click Target Disk Mode.
>
> When the computer has started up, a disk icon appears on the desktop
>   of the other computer.
>
> Transfer files by dragging them to and from the disk. Eject the disk
>   by dragging its icon to the Trash. While you drag, the Trash icon
>   changes to an Eject icon.
>
> On the computer you used as a disk, push the power button to shut it
>   down, then disconnect the cable.

After connecting to another Mac I simply copied the deleted file back into the correct directory from the host Mac.

I then booted my Mac successfully and repaired the file permissions via Disk Utility.